# Using max in a variable in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, max

can I use max function in a variable in XSLT 1? 
I need to find a maximum value inside some nodes and I'll need to call this from more places.
So I tried to create a template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:essox="urn:essox-scripts">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="Field001_max_dluznych_splatek">
        <xsl:param name="CrRep"/>
        <xsl:variable name="PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky">
            <xsl:value-of
             select="max($CrRep
                         /Response
                          /ContractData
                           /Installments
                            /InstDetail
                             /NrOfDueInstalments)" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="PocetDluznychSplatekKarty">
            <xsl:value-of
             select="max($CrRep
                          /Response
                           /ContractData
                            /Cards
                             /CardDetail
                              /NrOfDueInstalments)" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky
                             &gt;= $PocetDluznychSplatekKarty">
                <xsl:value-of select="$PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$PocetDluznychSplatekKarty"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XML Spy I get this error:

> `Error in XPath expression Unknown
>   function - Name and number of
>   arguments do not match any function
>   signature in the static context -
>   'max'.`

What is wrong? 
Thanks a lot,
Peter

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for your answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the well known maximum idiom:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:essox="urn:essox-scripts">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="Field001_max_dluznych_splatek">
        <xsl:param name="CrRep"/>
        <xsl:variable name="PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky">
            <xsl:call-template name="maximun">
                <xsl:with-param name="pSequence"
                 select="$CrRep
                          /Response
                           /ContractData
                            /Installments
                             /InstDetail
                              /NrOfDueInstalments"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky">
            <xsl:call-template name="maximun">
                <xsl:with-param name="pSequence"
                 select="$CrRep
                          /Response
                           /ContractData
                            /Cards
                             /CardDetail
                              /NrOfDueInstalments"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky
                             &gt;= $PocetDluznychSplatekKarty">
                <xsl:value-of select="$PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$PocetDluznychSplatekKarty"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="maximun">
        <xsl:param name="pSequence"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$pSequence">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: In a named template for reuse.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `max` function in XSLT 1.0. You can work around this by sorting your elements in descending order and then taking the value of the first one.

Here's another (slower) way to do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky"
        select="/test/PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky/val[not(../val &gt; .)][1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="PocetDluznychSplatekKarty"
        select="/test/PocetDluznychSplatekKarty/val[not(../val &gt; .)][1]" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when
                test="$PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky &gt;= 
                      $PocetDluznychSplatekKarty">
                <xsl:value-of select="$PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$PocetDluznychSplatekKarty" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample source document:

```
<test>
    <PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky>
        <val>22</val>
        <val>3241</val>
        <val>13</val>
    </PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky>
    <PocetDluznychSplatekKarty>
        <val>1</val>
        <val>3234341</val>
        <val>13</val>
    </PocetDluznychSplatekKarty>
</test>
```

Output:

```
3234341
```

The XPath in each variable's `select` looks like this:

```
/test/PocetDluznychSplatekSplatky/val[not(../val &gt; .)][1]
```

Or, select the `val` element having no `val` siblings with a greater value (i.e. the max).

(Obviously, you'll need to adjust the XPath to fit your source document.)

**Note:** The `sort` solution performs much better (assuming an `n*log(n)` sort implementation). The second approach needs to compare each `val` to every one of its siblings and is therefore quadratic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! How can I do this? I can sort elements in xslt, but I do not know how to sort them and put value of the first one into a variable.

Comment: Here's an example that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415934/xslt-max-node-value-problem

Comment: Thanks to @AakashM for the second approach, which I thought deserved a more complete example. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021667/how-to-get-equivalent-of-max-on-msxml6

Comment: @lwburk: You need to warnning that this XPath 1.0 only solution has **cuadratic complexity**.

Comment: @Alejandro - Yes, that's right. The sort solution performs much better (assuming an `n*log(n)` sort implementation), whereas this approach needs to compare each `val` to every one of its siblings (hence, quadratic). Whether or not this is an issue depends on your input size.